# Where is cron job installed by puppet located?

Tags: cron, puppet

I've created a cron job using puppet on an Ubuntu 14.04 system:

```
cron { 'packages':
  command => 'puppet apply /usr/lib/app/puppet-jobs/packages.pp',
  user    => 'root',
  hour    => 10,
  minute  => 25,
}
```

After one of my systems updated with puppet I can see the cron by running `sudo puppet resource cron`.

Yet if I look in `/etc/crontab` I don't see anything referencing my `.pp` file.

I also looked in each of the cron.d files with `cat /etc/cron.*/* | grep .pp` which returned nothing.

How can I find the actual cron file created by puppet?

Comment: Check this and see if it applies to you: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/cron/crontab.rb#L260-L269. Your specific case would be `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks, yes it was in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

Comment: Great; writing up answer in a sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can check the Puppet provider code for `cron` to see the actual commands Puppet is executing when it applies a `cron` resource. The relevant source code for the `cron` provider's use of the crontab directories is at: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/cron/crontab.rb#L260-L269.

Since you are running Ubuntu 14.04, your `osfamily` fact resolves to `Debian`, and the returned value for the crontab directory would be: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.